# Jquery slider plugin that supports "Multiple Ranged Handles"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have been looking for a Jquery UI slider pluging that supports mutiple ranged handles. The existing Jquery UI slider only supports one range set of values. I am looking for a slider that you can have muliple ranges. So a range with an inner range or two ranges that don't overlap.

Example:

R = handle

XX = Slider bar

= or - = Range between handles

XXR1------R1XXXR2--R2XXXXXXXXX

XXXR1----R2====R2-----R1XXXXXX

XXXR1--R2===R2----R3===R3--R1XXXX

I don't think there is a slider out there that can do this?? Just wanted to make sure before I go and write one.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't use multiple sliders (one for each range)? For this, you could use them to bound the other, so if one is an outside range, the other wouldn't be able to slide past the limits set by the outside.

Answer (score 9):

I've just released [Elessar](http://quarterto.github.io/Elessar) to fill this exact niche. colResizable is fine, but it's not really the right tool for the job.

[image]

Comment: @Matt Brennan I really like this but I need one without any gaps... And the first range would need to be fixed, possible to do? Thanks!

Comment: @tim, not with Elessar currently I'm afraid. Fixed ranges is on the roadmap but removing the gaps would be tricky with our current design.

Comment: The compatibility table at github is pretty old. At least for IE11 and Chrome 44 I can say, it works without a problem.

Comment: That's generated by testling-ci, which sadly has been totally broken since June 2014. I've an outstanding issue to move to Zuul and Saucelabs, I just haven't had the time or inclination to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it.

```
myarr = [ 65, 80, 90 ];
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: myarr,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if ( ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1] ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( ui.values[1] >= ui.values[2] ) {
                return false;
            }
            $(this).find(".range0").css({ "width": ui.values[0] + "%" });
            $(this).find(".range1").css({ "left": ui.values[0] + "%", "width": (ui.values[1]-ui.values[0])  + "%" }) ;
            $(this).find(".range2").css({ "left": ui.values[1] + "%", "width": (ui.values[2]-ui.values[1]) + "%" }) ;
            $(this).find(".range3").css({ "left": ui.values[2] + "%", "width": (100-ui.values[2]) + "%" }) ;
        },
        create: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).append('<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header range0" style="left: 0%; width: ' + myarr[0] + '%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #CF1920;"></div>');
                $(this).append('<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header range1" style="left: ' + myarr[0] + '%; width: ' + (100-myarr[1]) + '%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFE900;"></div>');
                $(this).append('<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header range2" style="left: ' + myarr[1] + '%; width: ' + (100-myarr[2]) + '%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #26CF2D;"></div>');
                $(this).append('<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header range3" style="left: ' + myarr[2] + '%; width: ' + (100-myarr[2]) + '%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #00BCFF;"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Im sure it can be optimized more, but this should give you the general idea