# How to create multi range time slider in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slider

I am using JQuery UI Time Slider.I want to get multiple Ranges with multiple Handles.
such like given below :

Start point 10:00 AM--Range---2:00 PM      4:00 PM---Range------8:00 PM  9:00 PM---Range---11:00 PM  Endpoint

I have tried this

```
$("#slider2").timeslider({

        sliderOptions: {
            ranges:  [false, true, false, true], 
            min: 300, 
            max: 3179, 
            values: [400, 800,1100,1600,2000,2500],
            step:5
        },

        errorMessage: '#max2',
        timeDisplay: '#time2',

        clickSubmit: function (e){
            var that = $(this).siblings('#slider2');

            $('#schedule2 tbody').append('<tr>' +
                '<td>' + that.attr('id') + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 0)) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 1)) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 2)) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 3)) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 4)) + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + that.timeslider('getTime', that.slider("values", 5)) + '</td>' + 
                '</tr>');
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
```

If anybody have a good example please share link with me to get these kind of output or please help me to modify this above code.

Thank you 
"Have a nice day ahead"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been searching for a solution myself, but it is hard to find a (good) solution. [Elessar](http://blog.153.io/Elessar/) seems a good option. It was given as an answer here: [jquery-slider-plugin-that-supports-multiple-ranged-handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529868/jquery-slider-plugin-that-supports-multiple-ranged-handles).

It's usage can be found on [Elassar's GitHub page](https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I tried. EDIT: But the essential part (link to Elessar) is already in the answer. I don't see what essential part is missing.

Comment: Try adding an example on how to use Elessar.

Comment: I think that should be done by Elessar's usage page. If the usage changes this answer would become invalid. I could add a link to that if you like.

Comment: @DaniloValente if the link vanishes, the library vanishes, and a usage example isn't much use here...

Comment: @MattBrennan We don't expect that a library will be vanished from the whole internet.